# `cordova build ios` - throw error, how to solve this?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

In my project folder, there is 2 platform for `android` and `ios`. when i run the command for `android` like : `cordova build android` - works fine without any issue.

in case if i run for `ios` like : `cordova build ios` - getting error like this:

`Using this version of Cordova with older version of cordova-ios is being deprecated. Consider upgrading to cordova-ios@4.0.0 or newer.`

`'C:\Projects\stic\platforms\ios\cordova\build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

`Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1`

But when i check for my `cordova version` like `cordova --v` out puts like : `6.4.0`

So what is wrong here. how to solve this?

any one help me here?

Comment: Please use `cordova platform ls` to see your platform versions. `cordova --v` only references the cordova cli version number

Answer (score 2):

You may have the latest version of cordova. But the iOS platform you have may be of the older version that got created prior to cordova update which is incompatible with the latest cordova version. You have two options to resolve this issue.

1. You can remove the iOS platform and readd it once again which adds the latest compatible iOS platform using following commands:

   > cordova platform rm ios
   >
   > cordova platform add ios
2. You can update the existing iOS platform to latest compatible version using following command:

   > cordova platform update ios